# Why is my script working but it shows a syntax error in console?

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, syntax-error

upon inspecting my console I get the error like below:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token.

I've traced back this line to my script in the footer portion of my folder and the line goes

```
 $('<?php echo $active_accordion_id ?>').addClass('show');
```

My noob question is this, why is this an error? This prints out what is needed for me to toggle the active accordion upon visiting the respective pages, according to the ID passed in each respective controller function. Since it is working as intended I am confused as to why it is an error.

Should I be bothered to change it since it is working as intended but it does bother me when I go into inspect mode. I would think that the best practice is to deal with this even if there might be no ramification from it (I hope not!). Shed some light if it would.

Thank you for reading my question!

Comment: Just curious. Can you give some example of the output that line generates?

Comment: Hi Tim, it does not generate an output, the script is just meant to add a class to the accordion to toggle it to be selected/active/show. So let's say I have an accordion with 3 tabs, each single tab has their respective id, let's say (#one, #two, #three). In the controller I load the ID with respect to showing which page, when page one is loaded, #one of the accordion is active/showing/not collapsed, and if page two is loaded #two of the accordion is active while the rest is collapsed and so on and so forth.

Comment: Well it will if you view the source in the generated HTML. You can do that in the browser. So it might be an idea to look around that area and see what shows up. Just a thought.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed why the error appears. All pages that loads the script doesn't necessarily have the accordion ID defined, so the error shows on those pages alone in console. So all I did is to assign null values for the active_accordion_id on those pages to not have that error appear.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's not good to call and use PHP functions directly in the script.
You can create a hidden input tag for your element what you want to add some class in your view

your view:

```
<input type="hidden" id="element_id" value="<?php echo $active_accordion_id; ?>">
```

your javascript code

```
var id = $("#element_id").val();
$('#'+id).addClass('show');
```

Comment: Yeah this method sounds better and I know I've used it before sometime last year on a different project but somehow I could not recall it this time around which is why I resorted to this method. Will give it a go and see if it goes away.